# Finding the minterm expression of F + G

Tags: logic

I have a question that asks me to find the minterm expression of two functions added together. The two functions in this case are

F = `m(0,4,5,6)`

G = `m(0,3,6,7)`

At the moment my reasoning is that the minterm expression of F + G would be the combined minterms of each function, taking out any repetition. So the result would be:

H = `m(0,3,4,5,6,7)`

but I feel the problem *cant* be that simple, this obviously isn't the correct solution. Would finding the solution require me to break up the minterm expressions of each function back into their variable, **then** add them together and simplify? Thank you for any input

Comment: What is $f+g$? The OR of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: What is $m(0,4,5,6)$?

Comment: why do you think this is not a correct solution? It is not minimized solution, but in terms of minterms, I dont think there is anything wrong. Remember minterms expression should contain all variables. In this case all three.

Comment: Can you explain your notation? I have no idea what you're talking about. Explain what a minterm is, what a minterm expression is, what $m(0,4,5,6)$ means, and what $F+G$ is.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Minterm is a completely standard term, which does not need to be defined. (A minterm is a conjunction in which every variable appears exactly once, either positively or negatively.)

Comment: @David A minterm is also a minimal 1-input of a monotone function. Evidently here a minterm has a different definition. So while being a complete standard term, it has at least two standard incompatible definitions! (Like the set of natural numbers, which might or might not contain zero.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my interpretation of your notation. The function $F = m(0,4,5,6)$ is in fact
$$ F = (x \land y \land z) \lor (\bar{x} \land y \land z) \lor (\bar{x} \land y \land \bar{z}) \lor (\bar{x} \land \bar{y} \land z). $$
(Perhaps positive and negative literals are switched, and possibly I am reading the bits in reverse order.)

The notation $F+G$ just means $F \lor G$. In that case, $m(S) + m(T) = m(S \cup T)$. Similarly, if $FG$ means $F \land G$, then $m(S)m(T) = m(S \cap T)$. Finally, the negation of $m(S)$ is $m(\bar{S})$. Basically, $m(S)$ is the function which is true on the truth assignments in $S$, so we can identify it with $S$. Boolean operations on functions correspond to boolean operations on sets.